# Perpendicular lines create a similar triangle?

Tags: geometry

[image]

In my physics book, it says that since both $V_1$ and $V_2$ are perpendicular to the lines joining them to the center of the circle (the blue radius lines), this means that the blue lined triangle (when joined) is a similar triangle to ($V_1 + \Delta V)$, thus making the angle between $V_2,  V_1$ being $\theta$.

This is confusing for me, because when searching the internet, it says that there are only two means of a triangle being similar to another, SSS, SAS, and AAA.  This text does not meet any of the rules.  What am I missing?

Comment: by the way, what do SSS, SAS, AAA mean? I never heard about such acronyms

Comment: SSS means Side-Side-Side, i.e. two triangles are "similar" (**not** equal) when the rispecitve couples of sides are *proportional*. AAA ia Angle-Angle-Angle, i.e.two triangles are "similar" (**not** equal) when the rispecitve couples of angles are *equal*. SAS is Side-Angle-Side, i.e.two triangles are "similar" (**not** equal) when we consider side $A$ and $A'$ respectively and $B$ and $B'$ and we have that the two couples of proportional and the two angles between $AB$ and $A'B'$ are *equal*.

Comment: See [Similarity (geometry)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_(geometry)) and also this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/422068/proof-of-triangles-are-similar-iff-corresponding-angles-are-equal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The angle beween $V_1$ and $V_2$ is $\theta$ because $V_2$ is obtained by a rotation of $V_1$ by $\theta$, as you can check by translating them to the origin ($V_1$ forms an angle $\pi/2$ with the $X$-axis, while $V_2$ $\pi/2+\theta$). If you want to translate this in a language of similiar triangels you can, but personally I see it more clearly by thinking about rotations.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the *similarity* between the triangles, the previous answer shows us that the blue triangle formed with the two sides of lenght $r$ and the third one $\Delta r$ [*Note* : it is not the space travelled on the circular path, but the *vector* "displacement"], and the other triangle formed by the vectors $V_1$, $V_2$ and $\Delta V$ are similar.

This is so because $|V_1| = |V_2| = r ∗ \omega$, thus :

> $$\frac{|V_1|}{|r|}=\frac{|V_2|}{|r|}$$

and the angle formed by $V_1$ and $V_2$ is equal to $\theta$.

Thus we apply the SAS criteria for silmilarity (Side-Angle-Side) and conclude with similarity.

Having shown this, we have that also the third couple of sides must be proportional, i.e. :

> $$\frac{|\Delta V|}{|\Delta r|} = \frac{|V_1|}{|r|}=\frac{|V_2|}{|r|}$$

Thus also $|\Delta V|$ and $|\Delta r|$ are proportional with *ratio* $\omega$ .

Comment: Just a question.  How did you get $\Delta V = \Delta s * V / r$

Comment: @Jason - You are right : having $\Delta V = \Delta r ∗ \omega$, [with $\Delta r$ and **not** $\Delta s$], due to the fact that in *uniform circular motion* : $V = r ∗ \omega$, substituting $V/r$ in place of $\omega$, we get : $\Delta V = \Delta r ∗ V/r$.